# no wp_nav_menu after installing polylang

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

After I installed polylang, my `wp_nav_menu` have disappeared and all the content after. I have deactivated polylang and the problem still persists.

If I remove `wp_nav_menu();` the rest of the content appears, it seems that something is stuck at the menu.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign your post,page to default languages.
and after add new languages it will work..
     go to 
          settings-->languages-->settings panel 
            there is first check box in red line check true that and save after see